# How to put (change or update) an image for testing API using ROBOT FRAMEWORK

Tags: api, selenium, robotframework

I have using this code, but for profileImage not changes. Am I miss something?

```html
create session           MySession                           ${base_rul}
    ${binary}=               Get Binary File                     ${CURDIR}\\boy.jpg
    ${encode}=               Evaluate                            base64.b64encode(b'$binary').decode('utf-8')    
    ...                      modules=base64
    ${headers}=              Create Dictionary                   fingerprint=1652435559794       
    ...                      authToken=${authToken}  
    ${body}=                 Create Dictionary                   Content-Type=multipart/form-data    
    ...                      Accept=application                  firstName=Pandi                     
    ...                      lastName=Pranata                    contact=65|999998877       
    ...                      email=pandirotama@yahoo.com         profileImage=${encode}               removeImage=0
    ${response}=             PUT On Session                      MySession                            /users/my-profile               
    ...                      data=${body}                        headers=${headers}
    log to console           ${response.status_code}
    log to console           ${response.content}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I (personally) understand - are you asking why after a PUT request to an unnamed api it doesn't do what it is supposed to? If yes - what does this have to do with Robot Framework, shouldn't that be a question to the API developers?

Comment: Hi, Todor Minakov, 
Actually when I use postman tools, the image can successful updated with status is 200. but when I use robot framework automation to Testing the API to update the image, the image has not changes but status is 200 with the response will given "no image change". Do you got what I mean, Don't you?

Comment: I get it, but still don't see how it's a question about the used framework. In the reverse situation, where postman call didn't change it - would you create a SO question "I have this private api, but postman is to blame it doesn't work"? To see what is happening - why it isn't changing the image - you should check what is the content of the request, is it conforming to the api's specs, and that service's log. At the end it'll probably turn up to be something trivial - incorrect encoding, or multipart, or something - and then it is a RF question - "how to change/set X in RF put request".

Comment: Hi @TodorMinakov, For the content of the request that has not changes is "profileImage". This content can updating the image by postman but didn't by Robot framework. Actually I dont know, am I wrong creating script or miss something in my script. Have you ever used a robot framework to test APIs?